# Looping scanf horizontally

Tags: c, scanf

If I use this code:

```
int a, b[100];
scanf("%d", &a);
for (int x = 0; x < a; x++) {
    scanf(" %d", &b[x]);
}
```

For example if

1st input: 3
2nd input: 4
3rd input: 3
4th input: 1

The output on the screen will be like this (because I use enter at the end of the `scanf` on every loop)

```
3
4
3
1
```

I want to make a code which will loop the second `scanf` in the `for` loop horizontally without pressing enter (but use space) until the end of the loop, like this:

```
scanf(" %d %d %d", &b[x], &b[x+1], &b[x+2]);
```

Comment: Did you try to use space, not enter? If you enter `4 0 1 2 3<enter>` you should get finally `a = 4` and `b[] = {0, 1, 2, 3}`.

Answer (score 1):

You can type the count and the entries on a single line, separated by spaces and the current code will parse them in a single uninterrupted flow because `scanf()` skips any whitespace before a value for `%d`, be it spaces, tabs, newlines...

Note that the format `" %d"` is redundant: `%d` skips any pending whitespace before the integer, and a space in the format string means exactly the same thing. Just use `scanf("%d", &b[x]);`

Note also that you should add a safety check to avoid scanning values beyond the end of the array and you should test the return value of `scanf()` to avoid undefined behavior on invalid input.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int a, x, b[100];
    if (scanf("%d", &a) == 1) {
        for (x = 0; x < 100 && x < a; x++) {
            if (scanf("%d", &b[x]) != 1)
                break;
        }
        printf("read %d values:", x);
        for (int i = 0; i < x; i++)
            printf(" %d", b[i]);
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `scanf` function will read and ignore any whitespace characters encountered before the next non-whitespace character (**whitespace characters include spaces, newline** and tab characters). A single whitespace in the format string validates any quantity of whitespace characters extracted from the stream (including none).

So whether you use ENTER (newline) or a SPACE (single or multiple) does not make a difference for reading the input values in this case.

See this online [reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/) for `scanf` for more details on how scanf works.